# Node.js test coverage

Tags: node.js, unit-testing, test-coverage

Could anyone, please, recommend simple test coverage tool for Node.js without using Mocha because I use simple functions from `assert` module of Node in my own test framework.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The standard library for code coverage is [nyc](https://www.npmjs.com/package/nyc), so that's my suggestion; however, you aren't going to get code coverage to work with a test framework you came up with yourself for free -- you'll need to make sure you are instrumenting the appropriate source files so the report contains what you expect.

The following links, which discuss non-standard uses of nyc (non-standard meaning, not jasmine or mocha) might be useful - one for classic istanbul, one for the newer nyc:
https://github.com/gotwarlost/istanbul/issues/574
https://github.com/istanbuljs/nyc/issues/548

Answer (score 1):

You can use Jest and Supertest.

- Jest -> https://jestjs.io/
- SuperTest -> https://www.npmjs.com/package/supertest

Comment: Yes! and i keep my answer.

Comment: Jest actually has nyc built-in. So jest comes with test-coverage.